# Selecting subclass attributes with Class Table Inheritance (Table Per Type)

Tags: sql, sqlite, inheritance

I have an inheritance schema that follows the Table Per Type pattern:

```
Harvesters  
harvester_id | description

Harvester_A  
harvester_id | propertyA_1 | propertyA_2

Harvester_B
harvester_id | propertyB_1 | propertyB_2
```

where *Harvester_A.harvester_id* and *Harvester_B.harvester_id* are foreign keys referencing *Harvesters.harvester_id*.

I have a fourth table:

```
Equipment_Set
equipment_set_id | ... | harvester_id
```

*Equipment_Set.harvester_id* is a foreign key to *Harvesters.harvester_id*.

How do I get the attributes of the specific subclass without knowing in advance which subclass I want? I.e. I have some Equipment_Set and want to get specific Harvester_A or Harvester_B attributes about its harvester_id depending on which subclass it is, but do not know in advance which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

Either put all tables together with outer joins (in the result, all the 'wrong' columns will be NULL):

```
CREATE VIEW Harversters_A_or_B AS
SELECT harvester_id,
       description,
       propertyA_1,
       propertyA_2,
       propertyB_1,
       propertyB_2
FROM Harvester
LEFT JOIN Harvester_A USING (harvester_id)
LEFT JOIN Harvester_B USING (harvester_id);
```

Or put all properties into the *same* columns using a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) (all the 'wrong' joins will return no rows):

```
CREATE VIEW Harversters_A_or_B AS
SELECT harvester_id,
       description,
       propertyA_1 AS property1,
       propertyA_2 AS property2,
       'A' AS type
FROM Harvester
JOIN Harvester_A USING (harvester_id)
UNION ALL
SELECT harvester_id,
       description,
       propertyB_1,
       propertyB_2,
       'B'
FROM Harvester
JOIN Harvester_B USING (harvester_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ultimately decided to go a different route than TPT, but this provided good insight. I need to refresh myself on joins.